# how to encrypt data of user like (name , password , roles ,subscriptions) into token and put it into one cell in database

Tags: sql, .net, model-view-controller

how to encrypt data of user like (name , password , roles ,subscriptions) into token and put it into one cell in database

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate your question further ? Please explain what technology your as using, what is the issue with the implementation of encryption associated to this technology. What do you mean by "token" exactly, how do you intend to use it ? Thanks

Comment: i'm using asp.net mvc  .. i want to store data of user encrypted in one cell in database .. every user should have a cell contains all his data encrypted.. is that possible?

Comment: Depends on the dbms used.

Comment: If encryption is to be done at a client side, most DBMSes have a data type to store arbitrary binary value. E.g. varbinary at ms sql server. Check you DBMS data types and choose the appropriate one.

Comment: i think.. encrypt data and put it in object of string and save it to data base .. am i right??